# Macro is copying only the visible cells

Tags: excel

Macro is copying only the visible cells of filtered rows though i did not use to copy only the visible cells. How do i make my macro to copy all the cells though they are invisble in the sheet

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Remove the filter and then copy.

Comment: @Reafidy I appreciate your help but the condition is, macro should not change filter setting. and the sheet should not be unfiltered by the macro, if even unfiltered by the macro for copying, it restore back like before , but its impossible to get back filters when we set autofiltermode = false .

Comment: please help me with these how do i copy even if they are invisible without changing filter settings , well i thought of variants, but the problem is some of the cells have background colors and variants picks only the data but not colors so i dont know what to do !

Comment: Then you may need to save the users autofilter settings, remove the filter, run your code then restore the autofilter settings.  Let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: @Reafidy how do i save users autofilter setting?

Comment: niko, what exactly did you need to copy, and does this need to be added to an existing sheet location, or to a new sheet?

Comment: @brettdj This should be copied to a new sheet , I mean i should copy all the cells not just visible cells of the filtered data even the rows which are hidden should be copied to other sheet range 1500 to 3500 , macro should not care if its hidden or filtered

Comment: niko, if thats the case then can't you simply copy your entire existing sheet using `ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)` to copy this to the last sheet position and then delete any unneeded rows, remove filtering an necessary from the next sheet etc?

Comment: @brettdj I got these idea but unfortunatly I got 30000 rows so copying the 30000 rows and deleting 28000 rows , its unnessary thing to do right?

Comment: niko, there are a few examples around for storing autofilter settings. try this one:  http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=333961

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Niko,

In that case just copy the sheet and make two deletions, the code will run instantly. If your last row position is unknown then I can tweak this code to find the true last used row

```
Sub QuickKill()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Rows("1:1499").Delete
        .Rows("2001:30000").Delete
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's acceptable to copy only cell values and formulas (ie no formatting) you can use this

```
Sub CopyAllData()
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim rngFrom As Range
    Dim rngTo As Range

    ' set a reference to the range to be copied, eg
    Set rng = [2:8]
    ' get the data
    v = rng.Formula

    ' set a range to the desitination, eg
    Set rngTo = [8:12]
    ' put the data
    rngTo.Formula = v

End Sub
```

**EDIT**
Just saw your comment to niko, seems you *do* want the format too.  Copying one row at a time does the trick
I initially tried `rngTo.Hidden = FALSE` instead of `rngTo.RowHeight = 15`, but it returns an error, don't know why

```
Sub CopyAll()
    Dim rngFrom As Range
    Dim rngTo As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim OldCalc As XlCalculation

    On Error GoTo Cleanup

    OldCalc = Application.Calculation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    ' set a reference to the range to be copied, eg
    Set rngFrom = [2:12]

    ' set a range to the desitination first row, eg
    Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rngTo = sh.[2:2]

    ' copy each row in turn and restore the copied row height
    For i = 1 To rngFrom.Rows.Count
        rngFrom.Rows(i).Copy rngTo
        rngTo.RowHeight = 15
        Set rngTo = rngTo.Offset(1, 0)
    Next

Cleanup:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = OldCalc

End Sub
```

Comment: copying each row when you got 2000 rows ,is a time consuming process isnt that?

Comment: @niko sure is!  There are ways to improve it though, I'll edit to include them